# Google AppInvites break build

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-app-invites

Part of our app's `build.gradle` is this:

```
tasks.withType(com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageApplication) { pkgTask ->
    pkgTask.jniFolders = new HashSet<File>()
    pkgTask.jniFolders.add(new File(projectDir, 'libs'))
}
```

For some reason when setting up AppInvites, build starts failing with following error:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Cannot set the value of read-only property 'jniFolders' on task ':app:packageProdDebug'.
```

Comment: Can you change your property `jniFolders` i/o for write?

Comment: @bjiang I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: I am also seeing this when trying to use [Android Studio Instant Run](https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/tech-docs/instant-run)

Comment: have you found the solution?

Comment: @MounirElfassi I've marked the answer.

Comment: thanks, what helped me is changing the gradle version to 1.3.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same error when I tried to use Instant Run.

Fixed by adding this instead:

```
android {
  sourcesets {
    main {
      jniLibs.srcDir new File(buildDir, 'lib')
    {
  }
}
```

Reference: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adt-dev/OqDyZ5VN-QM

Answer (score 4):

Change the gradle version to 1.3.1.

```
 dependencies {
     classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'
 }
```

Comment: I'm using 1.5 and it's still the same.

Comment: I got error in git 2.5, and have to downgrade to 1.3.1 so try this specific version !