# Cannot set the value of read-only property 'jniFolders' on task ':android:packageDebug'

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I wanted to open up and project in Android studio that I haven't worked on in a while, but when Android Studio tries to load the project it fails with this error message:

```
Error:(21, 0) Cannot set the value of read-only property 'jniFolders' on task ':android:packageDebug'.
```

I click on the link to the `build.gradle` and I guess these lines are the problem ...

```
// needed to add JNI shared libraries to APK when compiling on CLI
tasks.withType(com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageApplication) { pkgTask ->
    pkgTask.jniFolders = new HashSet<File>()
    pkgTask.jniFolders.add(new File(projectDir, 'libs'))
}
```

I see an answer here: [Google AppInvites break build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33758421/google-appinvites-break-build) that says to ...

> Fixed by adding this instead:
>
> ```
> android {
>   sourcesets {
>     main {
>       jniLibs.srcDir new File(buildDir, 'lib')
>     {
>   }
> }
> ```

But the above answer is not very clear.  I am not sure what line to change and the braces in the answer do not seem to match up.

I am at a total loss at what to do?  Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Ok I had to change the start of my build.gradle file to this ....

```
android {
    buildToolsVersion project.androidToolsVersion
    compileSdkVersion project.androidSDKVersion.toInteger()
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            jniLibs.srcDir 'libs'
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
}

/*RBC
// needed to add JNI shared libraries to APK when compiling on CLI
tasks.withType(com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageApplication) { pkgTask ->
    pkgTask.jniFolders = new HashSet<File>()
    pkgTask.jniFolders.add(new File(projectDir, 'libs'))
}
RBC*/
```

I added the line:

```
jniLibs.srcDir 'libs'
```

and I commented out

```
// needed to add JNI shared libraries to APK when compiling on CLI
tasks.withType(com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageApplication) { pkgTask ->
    pkgTask.jniFolders = new HashSet<File>()
    pkgTask.jniFolders.add(new File(projectDir, 'libs'))
}
```

In the `C:\Users\plankton\Desktop\ThePlaneThatCouldntFly\flappytrip\android\build.gradle` file.

I came about this solution after reading this https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues/3027

Comment: Thanks man it works .But I lost quite a few hair strands though trying to solve that bug .

Answer (score 2):

I faced this same problem when trying to import the [libgdx-cookbook](https://github.com/saltares/libgdx-cookbook) samples from "Libgdx Cross-platform Game Development Cookbook" into Android Studio 2.1.1. In my case, it was solved by simply:

- importing the `/samples` project;
- not upgrading the Gradle plugin when prompted;
- updating `build.gradle` file under the android subproject to make it use the `buildToolsVersion` and `compileSkdVersion` that I had:

  ```
  buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
  compileSdkVersion 23
  ```
- trying again.

So it maybe has to do with the version of the Gradle plugin.